# Find longest substring without repeating characters

Tags: string, algorithm

Given a `string S` of `length N` find longest substring without repeating characters.

**Example:**

**Input:** "stackoverflow"

**Output:** "stackoverfl"

If there are two such candidates, return first from left. I need linear time and constant space algorithm.

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with ? Is there some reason why you can't just use a "brute force" approach ?

Comment: @Paul: I know brute-force solution, TC: O(n^2). I need linear time algorithm.

Comment: If you need O(n) then this should be stated in the question

Comment: I dont think you need o(n^2) for this for brute force.

Comment: @RajendraUppal: I'm only guessing, but the downvoter probably thought the question "does not show any research effort"... which is not a entirely unreasonable assessment...

Comment: [Wikipedia has a nice long read on that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) with pseudo code that is easily adoptable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. You are going to need a start and an end locator(/pointer) for the
   string and an array where you store information for each character:
   did it occour at least once?
2. Start at the beginning of the string, both locators point to the
   start of the string.
3. Move the end locator to the right till you find
   a repetition (or reach the end of the string). For each processed character, store it in the array.
   When stopped store the position if this is the largest substring. Also remember the repeated character.
4. Now do the same thing with the start locator, when processing
   each character, remove its flags from the array. Move the locator till
   you find the earlier occurrence of the repeated character.
5. Go back to step 3 if you haven't reached the end of string.

Overall: O(N)

Comment: This works only for something like ASCII strings. For Unicode strings, change array to hashtable.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev There are ~1 million Unicode chars.  This is entirely possible to fit into an array indexed by code point.

Comment: I do not understand step 4. Will someone please explain? Thanks.

Comment: for the `stackoverflow` example: after step 3 the end locator is just passed the second `o`, the start locator is still at the beginning of the string, you registered characters: `aceflkorstv` and `o` is the repeated one. You move the start locator till you see an `o`, and remove each letter from the set. so when you stopped the set will contain: `eflorv`.

Comment: It seems that that algorithm would fail given "ababcdefahijklab" where the correct answer is "bcdefahijkl"

Comment: @kasavbere is right. An even simpler counterexample: abadef. Your algorithm returns adef, when it should return badef. Problem is, you're not allowing substrings to overlap.

Comment: @kasavbere how does it make you feel that is wrong answer get 7 up-votes plus the check mark whereas your answer below seems to solve the problem? Me, I think it's a bit funny and a poor relevation that many programmers may not know how to read and would probably not have up-voted this answer were it written in code as opposed to English. :)

Comment: i don't see what is your problem guys... with the example `abadef`: 3) `ab` - repeated character found (next is `a`), stop. 4) move start locator after the repeated character `b`. 3) move the end locator... `badef`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think the wording is wrong. When you stop on finding a repeated element (in this case b), you stopped because you found a duplicate 'a'. If you move start locator to after the repeated character, you'd miss the substring starting with 'b' - which is 'badef'. Running time won't be O(N) either since you go back to look at the same elements again.

Comment: @Achilles Why would the running not be O(N), the start pointer and end pointer are always moving in the forward direction and each element would only be visited once by each pointer. I think this algorithm would work for the case mentioned.

Comment: @Banarun Imagine the following example: `adebacdef` ... you start off and find that `a` is repeating. You store `adeb` as longest substring and now go back to begin at `d`. Now you find that `d` is repeating, and current longest substring (`debac`) is longer, so update. Now go back and start at `e'...

Answer (score 10):

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class SubString {
    public static String subString(String input){

        HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();

        String longestOverAll = "";
        String longestTillNow = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);

            if (set.contains(c)) {
                longestTillNow = "";
                set.clear();
            }
            longestTillNow += c;
            set.add(c);
            if (longestTillNow.length() > longestOverAll.length()) {
                longestOverAll = longestTillNow;
            }
        }

        return longestOverAll;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "substringfindout";
        System.out.println(subString(input));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer and the best way to do it. Thanks a lot for posting this answer.

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal I don't think so .. this solution returns only one String as output. What if there are 2 max length sub strings?

Comment: It will not return right string because when you find duplicate you  should start from the beginning of the last duplicate

Comment: WRONG Solution!

Comment: Inside for loop need to add one more condition and use list to add multiple same occurrences of substring.  
if (longestTillNow.length() > longestOverAll.length()) {
                longestOverAll = longestTillNow;
             containLists.clear();
                
            }else if(longestTillNow.length() == longestOverAll.length()){
             containLists.add(longestTillNow);
             containLists.add(longestOverAll);
            } ex: kamineekamineeKamineeabcdefabcd  output : [ekamin, kamine, eKamin, kamine, efabcd, kamine, kamine]

Answer (score 7):

You keep an array indicating the position at which a certain character occurred last. For convenience all characters occurred at position -1. You iterate on the string keeping a window, if a character is repeated in that window, you chop off the prefix that ends with the first occurrence of this character. Throughout, you maintain the longest length. Here's a python implementation:

```
def longest_unique_substr(S):
  # This should be replaced by an array (size = alphabet size).
  last_occurrence = {} 
  longest_len_so_far = 0
  longest_pos_so_far = 0
  curr_starting_pos = 0
  curr_length = 0

  for k, c in enumerate(S):
    l = last_occurrence.get(c, -1)
    # If no repetition within window, no problems.
    if l < curr_starting_pos: 
        curr_length += 1
    else:
        # Check if it is the longest so far
        if curr_length > longest_len_so_far: 
            longest_pos_so_far = curr_starting_pos
            longest_len_so_far = curr_length
        # Cut the prefix that has repetition
        curr_length -= l - curr_starting_pos
        curr_starting_pos = l + 1
    # In any case, update last_occurrence
    last_occurrence[c] = k

  # Maybe the longest substring is a suffix
  if curr_length > longest_len_so_far:
    longest_pos_so_far = curr_starting_pos
    longest_len_so_far = curr_length

  return S[longest_pos_so_far:longest_pos_so_far + longest_len_so_far]
```

Comment: This is in essence very similar to Karoly's solution. This has the advantage of requiring one pass instead of two on each character while his has the advantage of having slightly better space efficiency (his array is 0/1 therefore can be compacted into a bitmask).

Answer (score 2):

EDITED:

following is an implementation of the concesus. It occured to me after my original publication. so as not to delete original, it is presented following:

```
public static String longestUniqueString(String S) {
    int start = 0, end = 0, length = 0;
    boolean bits[] = new boolean[256];
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    for (; x < S.length() && y < S.length() && length < S.length() - x; x++) {
        bits[S.charAt(x)] = true;
        for (y++; y < S.length() && !bits[S.charAt(y)]; y++) {
            bits[S.charAt(y)] = true;
        }
        if (length < y - x) {
            start = x;
            end = y;
            length = y - x;
        }
        while(y<S.length() && x<y && S.charAt(x) != S.charAt(y))
            bits[S.charAt(x++)]=false;
    }
    return S.substring(start, end);
}//
```

ORIGINAL POST:

Here is my two cents. Test strings included. boolean bits[] = new boolean[256] may be larger to encompass some larger charset.

```
public static String longestUniqueString(String S) {
    int start=0, end=0, length=0;
    boolean bits[] = new boolean[256];
    int x=0, y=0;
    for(;x<S.length() && y<S.length() && length < S.length()-x;x++) {
        Arrays.fill(bits, false);
        bits[S.charAt(x)]=true;
        for(y=x+1;y<S.length() && !bits[S.charAt(y)];y++) {
            bits[S.charAt(y)]=true;
        }           
        if(length<y-x) {
            start=x;
            end=y;
            length=y-x;
        }
    }
    return S.substring(start,end);
}//

public static void main(String... args) {
    String input[][] = { { "" }, { "a" }, { "ab" }, { "aab" }, { "abb" },
            { "aabc" }, { "abbc" }, { "aabbccdefgbc" },
            { "abcdeafghicabcdefghijklmnop" },
            { "abcdeafghicabcdefghijklmnopqrabcdx" },
            { "zxxaabcdeafghicabcdefghijklmnopqrabcdx" },
            {"aaabcdefgaaa"}};
    for (String[] a : input) {
        System.out.format("%s  *** GIVES ***  {%s}%n", Arrays.toString(a),
                longestUniqueString(a[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more solution with only 2 string variables:

```
public static String getLongestNonRepeatingString(String inputStr){
    if(inputStr == null){
        return null;
    }

    String maxStr = "";
    String tempStr = "";
    for(int i=0; i < inputStr.length(); i++){
        // 1. if tempStr contains new character, then change tempStr  
        if(tempStr.contains("" + inputStr.charAt(i))){
            tempStr = tempStr.substring(tempStr.lastIndexOf(inputStr.charAt(i)) + 1);
        }
        // 2. add new character
        tempStr = tempStr + inputStr.charAt(i);
        // 3. replace maxStr with tempStr if tempStr is longer
        if(maxStr.length() < tempStr.length()){
            maxStr = tempStr;
        }
    }

    return maxStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm in JavaScript (w/ lots of comments)..

```
/**
 Given a string S find longest substring without repeating characters.
 Example:

 Input: "stackoverflow"
 Output: "stackoverfl"

 Input: "stackoverflowabcdefghijklmn"
 Output: "owabcdefghijklmn"
 */
function findLongestNonRepeatingSubStr(input) {
    var chars = input.split('');
    var currChar;
    var str = "";
    var longestStr = "";
    var hash = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        currChar = chars[i];
        if (!hash[chars[i]]) { // if hash doesn't have the char,
            str += currChar; //add it to str
        hash[chars[i]] = {index:i};//store the index of the char
    } else {// if a duplicate char found..
        //store the current longest non-repeating chars. until now
        //In case of equal-length, <= right-most str, < will result in left most str
        if(longestStr.length <= str.length) {
            longestStr = str;
        }
        //Get the previous duplicate char's index
        var prevDupeIndex = hash[currChar].index;

        //Find all the chars AFTER previous duplicate char and current one
        var strFromPrevDupe = input.substring(prevDupeIndex + 1, i);
        //*NEW* longest string will be chars AFTER prevDupe till current char
        str = strFromPrevDupe + currChar;
        //console.log(str);
        //Also, Reset hash to letters AFTER duplicate letter till current char
        hash = {};
        for (var j = prevDupeIndex + 1; j <= i; j++) {
            hash[input.charAt(j)] = {index:j};
        }
    }
  }
  return longestStr.length > str.length ? longestStr : str;
}

//console.log("stackoverflow => " + findLongestNonRepeatingSubStr("stackoverflow"));      
//returns stackoverfl

//console.log("stackoverflowabcdefghijklmn => " + 
findLongestNonRepeatingSubStr("stackoverflowabcdefghijklmn")); //returns owabcdefghijklmn

//console.log("1230123450101 => " + findLongestNonRepeatingSubStr("1230123450101")); //    
returns 234501
```

Answer (score 1):

> We can consider all substrings one by one and check for each substring whether it contains all unique characters or not. 
>   There will be n*(n+1)/2 substrings. Whether a substirng contains all unique characters or not can be checked in linear time by 
>   scanning it from left to right and keeping a map of visited characters. Time complexity of this solution would be O(n^3).`

```html
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


public class LengthOfLongestSubstringWithOutRepeatingChar {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 String s="stackoverflow"; 
 //allSubString(s);
 System.out.println("result of find"+find(s));
 }
 public static String find(String s)
 {
  List<String> allSubsring=allSubString(s);
  Set<String> main =new LinkedHashSet<String>();
  for(String temp:allSubsring)
  {
   boolean a = false;
   for(int i=0;i<temp.length();i++)
   { 
    for(int k=temp.length()-1;k>i;k--)
    {
     if(temp.charAt(k)==temp.charAt(i))
      a=true;
    }
   }
   if(!a)
   {
    main.add(temp);
   }
  }
  /*for(String x:main)
  {
  System.out.println(x); 
  }*/
  String res=null;
  int min=0,max=s.length();
  for(String temp:main)
  {
  if(temp.length()>min&&temp.length()<max)
  {
   min=temp.length();
   res=temp;
  }
  }
  System.out.println(min+"ha ha ha"+res+"he he he");
  return res;
  
 }
 //substrings left to right ban rahi hai

private static List<String> allSubString(String str) {
 List<String> all=new ArrayList<String>();
 int c=0;
 for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
   if (!all.contains(str.substring(j, i + 1)))
   {
    c++;
    all.add(str.substring(j, i + 1));
   }
  }
 }
 for(String temp:all)
 {
  System.out.println("substring :-"+temp);
 }
 System.out.println("count"+c);
 return all;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested and working. For easy understanding, I suppose there's a drawer to put the letters.

#### Function:

```
    public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        int maxlen = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        HashSet<Character> drawer = new HashSet<Character>(); 
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (drawer.contains(ch)) {
                //search for ch between start and end
                while (s.charAt(start)!=ch) {
                    //drop letter from drawer
                    drawer.remove(s.charAt(start));
                    start++;
                }
                //Do not remove from drawer actual char (it's the new recently found)
                start++;
                end++;
            }
            else {
                drawer.add(ch);
                end++;
                int _maxlen = end-start;
                if (_maxlen>maxlen) {
                    maxlen=_maxlen;
                }
            }
        }
        return maxlen;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another *O(n)* JavaScript solution. It does not alter strings during the looping; it just keeps track of the offset and length of the longest sub string so far:

```js
function longest(str) {
    var hash = {}, start, end, bestStart, best;
    start = end = bestStart = best = 0;
    while (end < str.length) {
        while (hash[str[end]]) hash[str[start++]] = 0;
        hash[str[end]] = 1;
        if (++end - start > best) bestStart = start, best = end - start;
    }
    return str.substr(bestStart, best);
}
 
// I/O for snippet
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function () {
    document.querySelector('span').textContent = longest(this.value);
});
```

```html
Enter word:<input><br>
Longest: <span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>I was asked the same question in an interview.</sup>

I have written Python**3** code, to find the *first occurrence* of the substring with all distinct chars. In my implementations, I start with index = 0 and iterate over the input string. While iterating used a Python dict `seems` to store indexes of chars in input-string those has been visited in the iteration.

In iteration, if char `c`, does not find in *current substring*  – raise KeyError exception

if `c` is found to be a duplicate char in the current substring (as `c` previously appeared during iteration –  named that index `last_seen`) start a new substring

```Python
def lds(string: str) -> str:
    """ returns first longest distinct substring in input `string` """
    seens = {}
    start, end, curt_start = 0, 0, 0
    for curt_end, c in enumerate(string):
        try:
            last_seen = seens[c]
            if last_seen < curt_start:
                raise KeyError(f"{c!r} not found in {string[curt_start: curt_end]!r}")
            if end - start <  curt_end - curt_start:
                start, end = curt_start, curt_end
            curt_start = last_seen + 1
        except KeyError:
            pass
        seens[c] = curt_end
    else: 
        # case when the longest substring is suffix of the string, here curt_end
        # do not point to a repeating char hance included in the substring
        if string and end - start <  curt_end - curt_start + 1:
            start, end = curt_start, curt_end + 1
    return string[start: end]
```

Answer (score 1):

Longest substring without repeating character in python

```
public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
    if(s.equals(""))
        return 0;
    String[] arr = s.split("");
    HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();

    int l_till = 1;
    int l_all = 1;
    map.put(arr[0],0);
    q.add(arr[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++){
        if (map.containsKey(arr[i])) {
            if(l_till > l_all){
                l_all = l_till;
            }
            while(!q.isEmpty() && !q.peek().equals(arr[i])){
                map.remove(q.remove());
            }
            if(!q.isEmpty())
               map.remove(q.remove());
            q.add(arr[i]);
            map.put(arr[i],i);
            //System.out.println(q);
            //System.out.println(map);
            l_till = q.size();
        }
        else {
            l_till = l_till + 1;
            map.put(arr[i],i);
            q.add(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    if(l_till > l_all){
                l_all = l_till;
            }
    return l_all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string LongestSubstring(string word)
        {
            var set = new HashSet<char>();
            string longestOverAll = "";
            string longestTillNow = "";

            foreach (char c in word)
            {
                if (!set.Contains(c))
                {
                    longestTillNow += c;
                    set.Add(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    longestTillNow = string.Empty;
                }

                if (longestTillNow.Length > longestOverAll.Length)
                {
                    longestOverAll = longestTillNow;
                }
            }

            return longestOverAll;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class LongestSubString2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "stackoverflowabcdefghijklmn";
        List<String> allOutPuts = new ArrayList<String>();
        TreeMap<Integer, Set> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Set>();
        for (int k = 0; k < input.length(); k++) {
            String input1 = input.substring(k);
            String longestSubString = getLongestSubString(input1);
            allOutPuts.add(longestSubString);
        }

        for (String str : allOutPuts) {
            int strLen = str.length();
            if (map.containsKey(strLen)) {
                Set set2 = (HashSet) map.get(strLen);
                set2.add(str);
                map.put(strLen, set2);
            } else {
                Set set1 = new HashSet();
                set1.add(str);
                map.put(strLen, set1);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(map.lastKey());
        System.out.println(map.get(map.lastKey()));
    }

    private static void printArray(Object[] currentObjArr) {
        for (Object obj : currentObjArr) {
            char str = (char) obj;
            System.out.println(str);
        }

    }

    private static String getLongestSubString(String input) {

        Set<Character> set = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
        String longestString = "";
        int len = input.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char currentChar = input.charAt(i);
            boolean isCharAdded = set.add(currentChar);
            if (isCharAdded) {
                if (i == len - 1) {
                    String currentStr = getStringFromSet(set);

                    if (currentStr.length() > longestString.length()) {
                        longestString = currentStr;
                    }
                }
                continue;
            } else {
                String currentStr = getStringFromSet(set);

                if (currentStr.length() > longestString.length()) {
                    longestString = currentStr;
                }
                set = new LinkedHashSet<Character>(input.charAt(i));
            }

        }

        return longestString;
    }

    private static String getStringFromSet(Set<Character> set) {

        Object[] charArr = set.toArray();

        StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
        for (Object obj : charArr) {
            strBuff.append(obj);

        }

        return strBuff.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not hurt to add an explanation to the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, and it was accepted by leetcode. However, after I saw the stats, I saw whole lot solutions has much faster result....meaning, my solution is around 600ms for all their test cases, and most of the js solutions are around 200 -300 ms bracket.. who can tell me why my solution is slowwww??

```js
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
  var arr = s.split("");

  if (s.length === 0 || s.length === 1) {
    return s.length;
  }

  var head = 0,
    tail = 1;
  var str = arr[head];
  var maxL = 0;
  while (tail < arr.length) {
    if (str.indexOf(arr[tail]) == -1) {
      str += arr[tail];
      maxL = Math.max(maxL, str.length);
      tail++;
    } else {
      maxL = Math.max(maxL, str.length);
      head = head + str.indexOf(arr[tail]) + 1;
      str = arr[head];
      tail = head + 1;
    }
  }
  return maxL;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting O(n^2) in python . I just want to know whether the technique mentioned by Karoly Horvath has any steps that are similar to existing search/sort algorithms ?

My code :

```
def main():
    test='stackoverflow'
    tempstr=''
    maxlen,index=0,0
    indexsubstring=''
    print 'Original string is =%s\n\n' %test

    while(index!=len(test)):
        for char in test[index:]:
            if char not in tempstr:
                tempstr+=char
                if len(tempstr)> len(indexsubstring):
                   indexsubstring=tempstr
            elif (len(tempstr)>=maxlen):
                   maxlen=len(tempstr)
                   indexsubstring=tempstr
                   break
        tempstr=''
        print 'max substring length till iteration with starting index =%s is %s'%(test[index],indexsubstring)
        index+=1

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Easy

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class longestsub {

    static Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String word = sn.nextLine();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("The Length is " +check(word));
    }
    private static int check(String word) {
        String store="";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (store.indexOf(word.charAt(i))<0) {
                store = store+word.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result word " +store);
        return store.length();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite optimized but simple answer in Python

```
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
      temp,maxlen,newstart = {},0,0
      for i,x in enumerate(s):
            if x in temp:
                  newstart = max(newstart,s[:i].rfind(x)+1)
            else:
                  temp[x] = 1
            maxlen = max(maxlen, len(s[newstart:i + 1]))
      return maxlen
```

I think the costly affair is `rfind` which is why it's not quite optimized.

Answer (score 0):

### This is my solution. Hope it helps.

```
  function longestSubstringWithoutDuplication(str) {
      var max = 0;

      //if empty string
      if (str.length === 0){
        return 0;
      } else if (str.length === 1){ //case if the string's length is 1
        return 1;
      }

      //loop over all the chars in the strings
      var currentChar,
          map = {},
          counter = 0; //count the number of char in each substring without duplications
      for (var i=0; i< str.length ; i++){
        currentChar = str.charAt(i);

        //if the current char is not in the map
        if (map[currentChar]  == undefined){
          //push the currentChar to the map
              map[currentChar] = i;
              if (Object.keys(map).length > max){
                 max = Object.keys(map).length;
              }
        } else { //there is duplacation
          //update the max
          if (Object.keys(map).length > max){
            max = Object.keys(map).length;
          }
          counter = 0; //initilize the counter to count next substring
          i = map[currentChar]; //start from the duplicated char
          map = {}; // clean the map
        }
      }


     return max;
    }
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on how this solves the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

here is my javascript and cpp implementations with great details: https://algorithm.pingzhang.io/String/longest_substring_without_repeating_characters.html

We want to find the longest substring without repeating characters. The first thing comes to my mind is that we need a hash table to store every character in a substring so that when a new character comes in, we can easily know whether this character is already in the substring or not. I call it as `valueIdxHash`.  Then,  a substring has a `startIdx` and `endIdx`. So we need a variable to keep track of the starting index of a substring and I call it as `startIdx`.  Let's assume we are at index `i` and we already have a substring `(startIdx, i - 1)`. Now, we want to check whether this substring can keep growing or not.

If the `valueIdxHash` **contains** `str[i]`, it means it is a repeated character. But we still need to check whether this repeated character is in the substring `(startIdx, i - 1)`. So we need to retrieve the index of `str[i]` that is appeared last time and then compare this index with `startIdx`.

- If `startIdx` is larger, it means the last appeared `str[i]` is **outside** of the substring. Thus the subtring can keep growing.
- If `startIdx` is smaller, it means the last appeared `str[i]` is **within** of the substring. Thus, the substring cannot grow any more. `startIdx` will be updated as `valueIdxHash[str[i]] + 1` and the new substring `(valueIdxHash[str[i]] + 1, i)` has potential to keep growing.

If the `valueIdxHash` **does not contain** `str[i]`,  the substring can keep growing.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class SubString {
    public static String subString(String input) {

        String longesTillNOw = "";

        String longestOverAll = "";
        HashMap<Character,Integer> chars = new HashMap<>();
        char[] array=input.toCharArray();
        int start=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            char charactor = array[i];
            if (chars.containsKey(charactor) ) {
                start=chars.get(charactor)+1;
                i=start;
                chars.clear();
                longesTillNOw = "";
            } else {
                chars.put(charactor,i);
                longesTillNOw = longesTillNOw + charactor;
                if (longesTillNOw.length() > longestOverAll.length()) {
                    longestOverAll = longesTillNOw;
                }
            }
        }
        return longestOverAll;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "stackoverflowabcdefghijklmn";
        System.out.println(subString(input));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified my solution to "find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters".

```
        public string LengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    var res = 0;
    var dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    var start = 0;

    for(int i =0; i< s.Length; i++)
    {
        if(dict.ContainsKey(s[i]))
        {
            start = Math.Max(start, dict[s[i]] + 1); //update start index
            dict[s[i]] = i;
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add(s[i], i);
        }

        res = Math.Max(res, i - start + 1);  //track max length
    }
    return s.Substring(start,res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
simple python snippet 
l=length p=position 
maxl=maxlength maxp=maxposition

Comment: what's the point of image ????  why not include the code....as a text ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to approach this problem in JavaScript.

A **Brute Force** approach is to loop through the string twice, checking every substring against every other substring and finding the maximum length where the substring is unique. We'll need two functions: one to check if a substring is unique and a second function to perform our double loop.

```
// O(n) time
const allUnique = str => {
  const set = [...new Set(str)];
  return (set.length == str.length) ? true: false;
}

// O(n^3) time, O(k) size where k is the size of the set
const lengthOfLongestSubstring = str => {
  let result = 0,
      maxResult = 0;
  for (let i=0; i<str.length-1; i++) {
    for (let j=i+1; j<str.length; j++) {
      if (allUnique(str.substring(i, j))) {
        result = str.substring(i, j).length;
        if (result > maxResult) {
          maxResult = result;
        }
      }
    }
  return maxResult;
  }
}
```

This has a time complexity of `O(n^3)` since we perform a double loop `O(n^2)` and then another loop on top of that `O(n)` for our unique function. The space is the size of our set which can be generalized to `O(n)` or more accurately `O(k)` where `k` is the size of the set.

A **Greedy Approach** is to loop through only once and keep track of the maximum unique substring length as we go. We can use either an array or a hash map, but I think the new [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) array method is cool, so let's use that.

```
const lengthOfLongestSubstring = str => {
  let result = [],
      maxResult = 0;

  for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    if (!result.includes(str[i])) {
      result.push(str[i]);
    } else {
      maxResult = i;
    }
  }

  return maxResult;
}
```

This has a time complexity of `O(n)` and a space complexity of `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Question:  Find the longest substring without repeating characters.
Example 1 :

```
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class example1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String a = "abcabcbb";
               // output => 3
            System.out.println( lengthOfLongestSubstring(a));

        }

        private static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String a) {
               if(a == null  || a.length() == 0) {return  0 ;}  
               int res = 0 ;
            Map<Character , Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
              for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
                  char ch = a.charAt(i);
                if (!map.containsKey(ch)) {
       //If ch is not present in map, adding ch into map along with its position
                    map.put(ch, i);

                }else {
/*
If char ch is present in Map, reposition the cursor i to the position of ch and clear the Map.
*/ 
                    i = map.put(ch, i);// updation of index
                     map.clear();
                }//else

                res = Math.max(res, map.size());

            }



            return res;
        }

    }
```

if you want the longest string without the repeating characters as output then do this inside the for loop:

```
String res ="";// global
    int len = 0 ;//global
 if(len < map.size()) {
     len = map.size();
    res = map.keySet().toString();
 }
System.out.println("len -> " + len);
System.out.println("res => " + res);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in O(n) time complexity.
Initialize three variables

1. Start (index pointing to the start of the non repeating substring, Initialize it as 0 ).
2. End (index pointing to the end of the non repeating substring, Initialize it as 0 )
3. Hasmap (Object containing the last visited index positions of characters. Ex : {'a':0, 'b':1} for string "ab")

Steps : 
Iterate over the string and perform following actions.

1. If the current character is not present in hashmap (), add it as to
   hashmap, character as key and its index as value.
2. If current character is present in hashmap, then

   a) Check whether the start index is less than or equal to the value present in the hashmap against the character (last index of same character earlier visited),

   b) it is less then assign start variables value as the hashmaps' value + 1 (last index of same character earlier visited + 1);

   c) Update hashmap by overriding the hashmap's current character's value as current index of character.

   d) Calculate the end-start as the longest substring value and update if it's greater than earlier longest non-repeating substring.

Following is the Javascript Solution for this problem.

```
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
    let length = s.length;
    let ans = 0;
    let start = 0,
        end = 0;
    let hashMap = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        if (!hashMap.hasOwnProperty(s[i])) {
            hashMap[s[i]] = i;
        } else {
            if (start <= hashMap[s[i]]) {
                start = hashMap[s[i]] + 1;
            }
            hashMap[s[i]] = i;
        }
        end++;
        ans = ans > (end - start) ? ans : (end - start);
    }
    return ans;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_substring(string):
   last_substring = ''
   max_substring  = ''
   for x in string:
       k = find_index(x,last_substring)
       last_substring = last_substring[(k+1):]+x
       if len(last_substring) > len(max_substring):
               max_substring  = last_substring        
   return max_substring

def find_index(x, lst):
   k = 0
   while k <len(lst):
      if lst[k] == x:
         return k
      k +=1
   return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

can we use something like this .

```
def longestpalindrome(str1):
    arr1=list(str1)
    s=set(arr1)
    arr2=list(s)
    return len(arr2)



str1='abadef'
a=longestpalindrome(str1)
print(a)
```

if only length of the substring is to be returned

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm:** 
 1) Initialise an empty dictionary **dct** to check if any character already exists in the string. 
 2) **cnt** - to keep the count of substring without repeating characters. 
3)**l** and **r** are the two pointers initialised to first index of the string. 
 4)loop through each char of the string. 
5) If the character not present in the **dct** add itand increse the **cnt**. 
6)If its already present then check if **cnt** is greater then **resStrLen**.
7)Remove the char from **dct** and shift the left pointer by 1 and decrease the count.
8)Repeat 5,6,7 till **l**,**r** greater or equal to length of the input string. 
9)Have one more check at the end to handle cases like input string with non-repeating characters.
Here is the simple python program to **Find longest substring without repeating characters**

```
a="stackoverflow"
strLength = len(a)
dct={}
resStrLen=0
cnt=0
l=0
r=0
strb=l
stre=l
while(l<strLength and r<strLength):
    if a[l] in dct:
        if cnt>resStrLen:
            resStrLen=cnt
            strb=r
            stre=l
        dct.pop(a[r])
        cnt=cnt-1
        r+=1    
    else:
        cnt+=1
        dct[a[l]]=1
        l+=1

if cnt>resStrLen:
    resStrLen=cnt
    strb=r
    stre=l

print "Result String Length : "+str(resStrLen)
print "Result String : " + a[strb:stre]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void longstr(char* a, int *start, int *last)
{
    *start = *last = 0;
    int visited[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        visited[i] = -1;
    }
    int max_len = 0;
    int cur_len = 0;
    int prev_index;
    visited[a[0]] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        prev_index = visited[a[i]];
        if (prev_index == -1 || i - cur_len > prev_index)
        {
            cur_len++;
            *last = i;
        }
        else
        {
            if (max_len < cur_len)
            {
                *start = *last - cur_len;
                max_len = cur_len;
            }
            cur_len = i - prev_index;
        }
        visited[a[i]] = i;
    }
    if (max_len < cur_len)
    {
        *start = *last - cur_len;
        max_len = cur_len;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "ABDEFGABEF";
    printf("The input string is %s \n", str);
    int start, last;
    longstr(str, &start, &last);
    //printf("\n %d  %d \n", start, last);
    memmove(str, (str + start), last - start);
    str[last] = '\0';
    printf("the longest non-repeating character substring is %s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
    int startIndex = 0;
    int maxLength = 0;
    //since we have 256 ascii chars
    int[] lst = new int[256];
    Arrays.fill(lst,-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        //to get ascii value of c
        int ic = (int) c;
        int value = lst[ic];
        //this will say to move start index to next index of the repeating char
        //we only do this if the repeating char index is greater than start index
        if (value >= startIndex) {
            maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, i - startIndex);
            startIndex = value + 1;
        }
        lst[ic] = i;
    }
    //when we came to an end of string
    return Math.max(maxLength,s.length()-startIndex);
}
```

This is the fastest and it is linear time and constant space

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented similar kind of solution in Java. I am returning the length of string instead of whole string.

Find below solution for the refernece:

```
public int getLengthOfLongestSubstring(String input) {
        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        String longestString = "";
        String oldString="";
        for(int i= 0; i < chars.length;i++) {
            if (longestString.contains(String.valueOf(chars[i])))
            {
                if(longestString.length() > oldString.length()){
                    oldString = longestString;
                }
                if(longestString.split(String.valueOf(chars[i])).length>1)
                    longestString= longestString.split(String.valueOf(chars[i]))[1]+(chars[i]);
                else{
                    longestString =String.valueOf(chars[i]);
                }
            }
            else{
                longestString =longestString+chars[i];
            }
        }
        return  oldString.length()< longestString.length()? longestString.length(): oldString.length();
    }
```

Or can use following link as a reference.

[Git URL](https://github.com/Urja/LeetCode/blob/master/medium/LongestString.java)

Answer (score 0):

i’ve also solved this problem, below my 2 solutions written in JavaScript (Brute Force and Sliding Window) + YouTube video with explanation https://youtu.be/1NzWlRP3yfI

```
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {number}
 */

// //BRUTE FORCE
// var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {

//     let count = 0;

//     for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
//         let char = s.charAt(i);
//         let set = new Set([char]);

//         for (let j = i+1; j < s.length; j++) {
//             let char = s.charAt(j);
//             if (set.has(char)) {
//                 break;
//             } else {
//                 set.add(char);
//             }
//         }

//         if (set.size > count) {
//             count = set.size;
//         }

//     }

//     return count;
// };

//SLIDING WINDOW
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {

    let count = 0;
    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;
    let n = s.length;
    let set = new Set();

    while (i < n && j < n) {
        let char = s.charAt(j);
        if(!set.has(char)) {
            set.add(char);
            j++;
            count = Math.max(count, j - i)
        } else {
            set.delete(s.charAt(i));
            i++;
        }
    }

    return count;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int longestsub(String str) {
    int res = 0;
    int start = -1;
    HashMap<Character,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        start = Math.max(start,hm.getOrDefault(c, start));
        res = Math.max(i -  start ,maxLen);
        hm.put(c,i); // update the index
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy python code:

```
value = 0 
substring = ""

for i in s:
  if i not in substring:
    substring += i
    value = max(value, len(substring))
  else:
    cut_index = substring.index(i)
    substring = substring[cut_index+1:] + i

return value
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified solution in javascript.

```js
function longestUniqueString(s) {    
      let i = 0;
      let j = 0;
      let max = 0;
      let set = {};
      let longestString = "";
        
      while(i < s.length - max){
        if(!set[s[j]]){
          set[s[j]] = s[j]; 
          j++;
          max = Math.max(max, j-i);
          if(max <= j-i) longestString = Object.keys(set).join(""); 
        }else{
          i++;
          j = i;
          set = {};
        }
      }
      
      return longestString;
}

// I/O for snippet
console.log(longestUniqueString("stackoverflow"));
```

Answer (score 0):

C# Solution for defining  length of the longest substring without repeating characters:

```
public int LengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                return 0;
        if (s.Length==1)
                return 1;
        var l = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                var tmp = "" + s[i];
                for (int j = i + 1; j < s.Length; j++)
                    if (tmp.Contains(s[j].ToString())) break;
                    else tmp += s[j];
                if (l < tmp.Length)
                    l = tmp.Length;
            }
            return l;
    }
```

Comment: To help others understand the concepts of your code it would be nice if you could explain what your code is doing.  (e.g. comments)

Answer (score 0):

**Leetcode accepted answer** *Longest substring without repeating character*

```
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function (s) {
    let str = '', count = 0, conatinSC = containsSpecialChars(s);
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i] != ' ') {
            if (str && ((conatinSC && str.match(/s[i]/) || (!conatinSC && str.match(s[i]))))) {
                if (count < str.length) {
                    count = str.length;
                }
                if (str[i - 1] == s[i]) {
                    str = s[i];
                } else {
                    str = str.substring(containsSpecialChars(s[i]) ? str.match(/s[i]/).index + 1 : str.match(s[i]).index + 1) + s[i];
                }

            } else {
                str += s[i];
                if (count < str.length) {
                    count = str.length;
                }
            }
        } else {
            count++;
            break;
        }

    }
    return count;
};
function containsSpecialChars(str) {
    const specialChars = /[`@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;
    return specialChars.test(str);
}
lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

## O(n) solution with few lines of python code

```
def longestSub(word):

  longest = word[0]
  length = 1
  for i in range(0, len(word)-1):
    current = word[i]
    next = word[i+1]
   # print(current,next)
    if(next not in longest):
      longest += next
      print(longest)
    else:
      longest = longest.replace(longest, "") + next
      print(longest)

    length = length if length > len(longest) else len(longest)

  print(length)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private static String LongestSubString(String word)
{
    char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();
    HashSet set = new HashSet();
    String longestOverAll = "";
    String longestTillNow = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        Character c = charArray[i];

        if (set.contains(c)) {
            longestTillNow = "";
            set.clear();
        }
        longestTillNow += c;
        set.add(c);
        if (longestTillNow.length() > longestOverAll.length())
        {
            longestOverAll = longestTillNow;

        }
    }

    return longestOverAll;
}
```

Comment: Why are you simply posting the same answer again? Just for the sake of reputations?