# Longest unique substring

Tags: c++, string

This question may seem repeated but I am posting it since I was not able to find the solution that I wanted.
If the input string is "abcaadafghae", I want the first longest unique substring (without repeated characters) which should be "dafgh". I got the below program for finding the length of this substring which is 5, but I want the substring itself as the output.

Thanks in advance.

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
  int n = s.length();
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  int maxLen = 0;
  bool exist[256] = { false };
  while (j < n) {
    if (exist[s[j]]) {
      maxLen = max(maxLen, j-i);
      while (s[i] != s[j]) {
        exist[s[i]] = false;
        i++;
      }
      i++;
      j++;
    } else {
      exist[s[j]] = true;
      j++;
    }
  }
  maxLen = max(maxLen, n-i);
  return maxLen;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find longest substring without repeating characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734474/find-longest-substring-without-repeating-characters)

Comment: The longuest substring of "abcaadafghae" is "abcaadafghae", there is some precision missing in your question. :)

Comment: @Johan: I want a longest susbtring without any repeated characters. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that this is a learning exercise, here is how you can modify your algorithm to find the longest unique substring.

Start by identifying the places in your code where you modify `maxLen`. There are three of them:

- The place where you set it to zero,
- The place where you set it to `max(maxLen, j-i)`, and
- The place where you set it to `max(maxLen, n-i)`

Replace `maxLen` with `maxStr`, and use it as follows:

- Replace assignment of zero with an assignment to an empty string,
- Replace assignment to `max(maxLen, j-i)` with a check `maxStr.length() < (j-i)`, and setting `maxStr` to substring of `s` from `i`, inclusive, to `j`, exclusive
- Replace assignment to `max(maxLen, n-i)` with a check `maxStr.length() < (n-i)`, and setting `maxStr` to substring of `s` from `i`, inclusive, to `n`, exclusive

Return `maxStr`, that would be your answer.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/fsGIC0)

Answer (score 0):

```
/*C++ program to print the largest substring in a string without repetation of character.
eg. given string :- abcabbabcd
largest substring possible without repetition of character is abcd.*/

     #include<bits/stdc++.h>
     using namespace std;
     int main()
     {
      string str,str1;
      int max =0;
      string finalstr;
      vector<string> str2;
      cin>>str;
    int len = str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(str1.find(str[i]) != std::string::npos)
        {
            str2.push_back(str1);
            char p = str[i];
            str1 = "";
            i--;
            while(p!=str[i])
                i--;
        }
        else
            str1.append(str,i,1);
    }
    str2.push_back(str1);

    for(int i=0;i<str2.size();i++)
    {
        if(max<str2[i].length()){
            max = str2[i].length();
            finalstr  = str2[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<finalstr<<endl;
}
```