# Find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters

Tags: java, string

So the problem I'm trying to solve this problem given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters. I'm aware of the HashMap based solution, but that fails in case of overlapping substrings.Here's my code.

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {

        Deque<Character> primary = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Deque<Character> secondary = new ArrayDeque<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() ; i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if(primary.contains(c)){
                while(primary.peek() != c){
                    secondary.offerLast(primary.poll());
                }
                secondary.offerFirst(c);
                primary = secondary;
                secondary.clear();
            }else{
                primary.offerFirst(c);
            }
        }
        return primary.size();

    }
```

This fails at the line where I do `primary = secondary` otherwise I think I'm doing it right logically. 
To test the correctness I'm using the string `dvdf` 
Can someone help me understand why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering this:

```
primary = secondary;
secondary.clear();
```

It's assignment by reference. You set `primary` and `secondary` to point to the same data and clear it. Is that your intention?

What about this:

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {

    Deque<Character> primary = new ArrayDeque<>();
    Deque<Character> secondary = new ArrayDeque<>();
    Deque<Character> longest = new ArrayDeque<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (primary.contains(c)) {
            // Store longest
            if (primary.size() > longest.size()) {
                longest = new ArrayDeque<>(primary);
            }

            while (primary.peek() != c) {
                secondary.offerLast(primary.poll());
            }
            secondary.offerFirst(c);
            primary = secondary;
            secondary = new ArrayDeque<>();  // Altered
        } else {
            primary.offerFirst(c);
        }
    }

    // Also check at end of line.
    if (primary.size() > longest.size()) {
        longest = primary;
    }

    return longest.size();
}
```

*OUTPUT*

- `dvdf` => 3
- `dvdfvadv` => 4

**EDIT**

Your logic is right. I just altered one line.

**EDIT**

Keep track of the longest.

Comment: Isn't the longest not repeating string in` dvdf` `vdf` which means the length should be 3.

Comment: This works on `dvdf` but I think even this will run into a bug. There's no guarantee that the current string is the longest string. Right?

Comment: I think we'd have to maintain a list to keep track of the longest string thus being formed.

Answer (score 1):

May not be exact answer you were looking. Try to avoid using ArrayDeque in a multi threaded env as it is not thread safe.

Go through this link::

[Find longest substring without repeating characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734474/find-longest-substring-without-repeating-characters?rq=1)

this returns a string. you can use .length() method and find the length as you require.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public class LongestSubstring {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(longestSub("abcdefgghij"));
//prints 7 abcdefg g is repeated character
    }
    public static int longestSub(String s) {
        if(s==null)
            return 0;
        boolean[] flag = new boolean[256];

        int result = 0;
        int start = 0;
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            char current = arr[i];
            if (flag[current]) {
                result = Math.max(result, i - start);
                // the loop update the new start point and reset flag array

                for (int k = start; k < i; k++) {
                    if (arr[k] == current) {
                        start = k + 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    flag[arr[k]] = false;
                }
            } else {
                flag[current] = true;
            }
        }

        result = Math.max(arr.length - start, result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't looking for a different approach or a solution. I want to understand what's wrong with my logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*C++ program to print the largest substring in a string without repetation of character.
eg. given string :- abcabbabcd
largest substring possible without repetition of character is abcd.*/

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str,str1;
    int max =0;
    string finalstr;
    vector<string> str2;
    cin>>str;
    int len = str.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(str1.find(str[i]) != std::string::npos)
        {
            str2.push_back(str1);
            char p = str[i];
            str1 = "";
            i--;
            while(p!=str[i])
                i--;
        }
        else
            str1.append(str,i,1);
    }
    str2.push_back(str1);

    for(int i=0;i<str2.size();i++)
    {
        if(max<str2[i].length()){
            max = str2[i].length();
            finalstr  = str2[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<finalstr<<endl;
    cout<<finalstr.length()<<endl;
}
```